# What is a correlated subquery ? Why is it different of a non-correlated subquery ? And why did we need Alias?

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

## My Problem

I have a question about subquery in SQL.

I try, among other things, to check **if I understood the principle of correlated subquery**, but also to understand **the interest of the aliases in this one.**

To do this, I will use an example and try to explain how I understand the correlated subquery.

---

## The Example

Consider the following Query as an example:

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders AS O
WHERE O.custid = C.custid
AND O.orderdate = '20070212');
```

From this Query, I separate the Outer and Inner Query :

Outer Query :

```
SELECT custid, companyname
FROM Sales.Customers AS C
WHERE EXISTS
```

Inner Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.Orders AS O
WHERE O.custid = C.custid
AND O.orderdate = '20070212'
```

---

## My Understanding

From what I understood this is the reason we can talk about correlated Subquery in this case:

**In SQL, a query is done line by line.** He will select for line 1 then for line 2, then line 3, etc.

Since in my Inner Query, I use C.custid (ie a column whose value will be read line by line by My Outer Query) and that I compare it to O.custid (a whole column which will also have to be read line by line).

**This query will need all the rows of my O array to be first examined before going to the next line in my C array. For this reason, this is a correlated SubQuery.**

In other words, **the Query will execute as follows:**

1. The Outer Query found the value of "custid" and "companyname" for my FIRST ROW in my C TABLE
2. The Inner Query gonna look at the first Row of my O TABLE
3. The Inner Query gonna compare the value of C.custid found in the FIRST ROW of the C TABLE to the value of the O.custid found in the FIRST ROW of the O TABLE
4. The Inner Query gonna compare the value of O.orderdate found in the FIRST ROW of the O TABLE to '20070212'.
5. The Inner Query gonna go at the NEXT ROW of my O TABLE
6. The Inner Query gonna repeat the step 2 to 5 with the NEXT ROW of the O TABLE instead of the FIRST ROW of the O TABLE until he arrive at the end of the O TABLE
7. The Outer Query gonna look at the next ROW
8. The Step 2-7 will repeat but this time, they gonna compare O.custid to the value of C.custid in the NEXT ROW and this, until the end of the C TABLE

---

## My Second Problem

Now, in case I correctly understood the principle of correlated subquery.
The question I ask myself is this:

**Why should we use aliases?**

In the example above, we could say that it is because we use two tables with each a column of the same name.
However, in a case where the two columns would not have been named both named "custid", what would have been the utility of the aliases ?

**Is it because the "SELECT" command modifies the table a certain way ?**

Because if the table is not modified, I have trouble understanding the necessity of aliases in correlated subquery.

***Note :*** *I know that Correlated Subquery can also be optimizated by using Join, but I really want to focus of the base of the correlated SubQuery.*

---

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, my understanding of the correlated subquery is good.

**In a non-correlated subquery :** 
**The Inner Query will be execute once** (in Total) 
But **in an Correlated Subquery,** it will be execute **once for each row of my outer query.**

However, I still don't know why an alias is needed.